# indexing a variable with "bracket notation" does not always work in ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am new to `ansible` and followed the instruction [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html)  which gives two notations for referencing key-value dictionaries.

```
foo['field1']
foo.field1
```

and says "Bracket notation always works". I try with

```
  vars: 
    - london: 
      - nodename : music0
      - card: Headphone 
      - mixer: Hardware


    - debug: 
        msg: nodename  "{{ london[0] }} " 
    - debug: 
        msg: nodename  "{{ london['nodename'] }} "
```

The first wint reference [0] seems ok:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "nodename  \"{u'nodename': u'music0'} \""
}
```

but not the bracket notation:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'nodename'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/frank/Data/ansibleHost/testVars.yml': line 29, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

What is the difference to the published example? I admit that I do not understand the error message... the `list object` should be `london` which has an `attribute` - or do I misunderstand the variable declaration?

I would appreciate a recommendation for a comprehensive tutorial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it seems your issue is the fact that you are mixing [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) and [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

- This is a dictionary, you can access elements out of it with `london.nodename` or `london['nodename']`

  ```yaml
  london: 
    nodename: music0
    card: Headphone 
    mixer: Hardware
  ```
- While what you have is a list of dictionary containing other lists of dictionaries:

  ```yaml
  foo:
    - london: 
      - nodename: music0
      - card: Headphone 
      - mixer: Hardware
  ```

  You can access this with a 0-based index syntax: `foo.0.london.0.nodename` but I higly suspect this is not the data structure you are looking for. In the same fashion as above, `foo[0]['london'][0]['nodename']` will work too
- For a further example of what a list would more looks like:

  ```yaml
  fruits:
    - banana
    - apple
    - orange
    - lemon
  ```

  And then for a further explanation about the 0-based index, you could, for example, access `orange` via `fruits.2` or `fruits[2]`

---

If you do not want to change you data structure:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ london.0.nodename }}"
      vars: 
        - london: 
          - nodename: music0
          - card: Headphone 
          - mixer: Hardware
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "music0"
}
```

Now why don't you have to say `0.london.0.nodename`, you will ask?
This is because `vars` does not expect a list but rather a dictionary, and Ansible is too kind with you and casts it as a dictionary.

Comment: worked perfectly!  and thank you for the explanation - I will change the data structure as you suggest, because that is what I probably wanted. I did not see that the example had no "-" for each entry. --  I still wonder where a computer scientist could learn to use ansible? any comprehensive text? -- would it be reasonable to compare the first structure with records and the second with arrays?

Comment: follow up: how to use the content of a variable (which has the value 'london') for the index. I tried  with the  data structure you suggested `  "{{ london[result.stdout] }} "  ` -- i.e. how to get the value out of a variable (I tried {{..}} but this did not work either).

Comment: I got it: "{{ vars[result.stdout]['nodename'] }} - I am still a bit confused, but slowly. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @user855443 I'd learn YAML, maybe in the short verison from [there](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) then for Ansible, that really depends what you want to achive with it. In the same site as the YAML quick tutorial, there is also something [that might be a good start pack](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

Comment: And maybe learn Python too. Will serve you for Data analysis as well as Ansible, since it is written in Python and concept like list and dictionnary are then inherited from the Python's world.

Comment: The YAML quick tutorial clarified a few things (but most were clear after the explanation in the answer). I know a bit of python (and 5 .. 20 other languages; started with Niklaus Wirth personally teaching me Pascal and then went to COBOL! My primary language at the moment is Haskell), but I want to use ansible just as a tool to manage the dozen computers we have in our homes, nothing too fancy. Thank you all for your help!